# Rails - How to test enum PostgreSQL data-type with rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec-rails

I'm using  shoulda-matchers to test enum.

```
describe 'enum' do
  it do
    should define_enum_for(:gender).
    with([:male, :female, :others])
  end
end
```

Recently, I changed the column at the DB to enum data-type, as showed [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/enumerated-types-with-activerecord-and-postgresql/)

My current enum definition at the user model.

```
  enum gender: {male:'male', female:'female', others:'others'}
```

After that, my test fails (obviously) and shows the follow message.

```
 1) User enum should define :gender as an enum with [:male, :female, :others] and store the value in a column with an integer type
```

How can I test that with rspec?

Comment: Could you show us how your enum is defined in model?

Comment: I update my question with the enum definition at the model @Vimsha

Answer (score 1):

Posting since I recently encountered the same issue.

You can specify the column type and values explicitly in RSpec:

```
it "defines an enum" do
  expect(field).to define_enum_for(:column_name)
                     .backed_by_column_of_type(:enum)
                     .with_values(male: "male", female: "female", others: "others")
end
```

Note:

- `:enum` column type if you have a corresponding postgres enum defined; otherwise you can also use `:string` here. For the `:enum` type, RSpec expect the value `:enum` rather than the name of the enum.